# I need to use current location of the user into select field in html

Tags: html

I need to find the route between start point and end point in google maps. For the start point i need user's current location to be pointed. End point has only 4 addresses. For start point i need to use geolocation in select field in html . I'm unable to get the logic can anyone help

Comment: did you read the google api docs? i promise it's in there. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

Comment: it is showing for mobile signal all everything. I dont find what i want to know